# Most useful plugins for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

What would be some of the top most used `Elasticsearch` plugins?
For example, monitoring data, mapping, or analysis plugin.

Answer (score 2):

OP didn't mention the ES version you are using. I am suggesting below plugins as they are easy to set-up, free and provides the admin interface for elasticsearch cluster.

I would recommend, For ES versions less than 2.x [KOPF plugin](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf) and for the latest version of ES, use [Cerebro](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro), which is from the same author of **kopf**.

**It offers an easy way of performing common tasks on an elasticsearch cluster. Not every single API is covered by this plugin, but it does offer a REST client which allows you to explore the full potential of the ElasticSearch API.**